# On factoring the resolvent equations of solvable quintics, septics, etc?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, radicals, factoring, quintics

**I. p = 11**

The minimal polynomial of $x=2\cos\frac{2\pi}{11}$ is,

$$x^5 +x^4 −4x^3 −3x^2 +3x+1 = 0$$

As is known, Method 1 solves it in the form,

$$x = \frac15\left(A+y_1^{1/5}+y_2^{1/5}+y_3^{1/5}+y_4^{1/5}\right)$$

where the $y_k$ are the four roots of the quartic resolvent. There is a slight problem when all $y_k$ are complex. So alternatively, we can have a Method 2 using just **one** root $y_1$,

$$y_1= -\frac{ab}{11} =-\frac{11}{4} \left(89-25 \sqrt{5}-5 \sqrt{-(410+178 \sqrt{5})}\right) $$

which surprisingly has *factors*,

$$a=\frac{11}{4}\left(-1+5\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{-10(5+\sqrt{5})}\right)$$

$$b=\frac{11}{4}\left(-31+5\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{-10(85+31\sqrt{5})}\right)$$

and we can use this factorization to solve the minimal polynomial in a different way as,

$$x_k = -\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{\beta^{-1}}+\frac{1}{\beta^0}+\frac{11}{\beta^1}+\frac{a}{\beta^2}+\frac{b}{\beta^3} \right)$$

where $\color{blue}{\beta^5+y_1=0}$. Of course, this quintic in $\beta$ has five solutions which gives the five $x_k$. But since Method 2 takes the fifth root of only **one** complex number $y_1$, this avoids the problem of Method 1.

---

**II. p = 29**

The minimal polynomial of $x=2\big(\cos\frac{2\pi}{29} + \cos\frac{24\pi}{29}\big)$is,

$$x^7 + x^6 - 12x^5 - 7x^4 + 28x^3 + 14x^2 - 9x + 1 = 0$$

This can be solved by Method 2 as well. (I still have to locate my notes back [from 2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1339017/4781).)

---

**III. p = 43**

The minimal polynomial of $x=2\big(\cos\frac{2\pi}{43} + \cos\frac{12\pi}{43} +\cos\frac{14\pi}{43}\big)$ is,

$$x^7 + x^6 - 18x^5 - 35x^4 + 38x^3 + 104x^2 + 7x - 49 = 0$$

Fortunately, I found my notes for this. Its sextic resolvent is,

$$43^{21} - 109288043513083876814190246493y + 343597088843572196970429y^2 - 781038748669395217y^3 + 1264067561247y^4 - 1479157y^5 + y^6 = 0$$

This can be greatly simplified and solved merely as a quadratic,

$$y^2 - 43(8265 - 7889r + 343r^2)y + 43^7 = 0$$

using the roots of $r^3+r^2-2r-1=0$, the minimal polynomial of $r = 2\cos\frac{2\pi}7$. (The sextic can be recovered by eliminating $r$ using resultants as in this [WA calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Resultant%5B271818611107%20-%2043*%288265%20-%207889*r%20%2B%20343*r%5E2%29*y%20%2B%20y%5E2%2C%20-1%20-%202%20r%20%2B%20r%5E2%20%2B%20r%5E3%2Cr%5D).) Like the quartic root, the sextic root $y$ also factors, but in ***two*** ways,

$$y_1 = \frac{43^4pq}{43} = \frac{43^4rs}{43}$$

where $(p,q,r,s)$ are the *appropriate* roots of,

$$43^3 - 1849p + 645p^2 + 41p^3 + 15p^4 - p^5 + p^6 = 0\\ 
43^3 + 282983q + 511267q^2 + 615413q^3 + 511267q^4 + 282983q^5 + 43^3q^6 = 0$$

and,

$$43^2 - 1763r - 1553r^2 + 3277r^3 - 1553r^4 - 1763r^5 + 43^2r^6 = 0\\ 43^4 + 1577197s + 329337s^2 + 50161s^3 + 7659s^4 + 853s^5 + 43s^6= 0$$

For example, if we choose $y_1 \approx -22340.0362 + 520883.4167i$, then,

\begin{align}
p &\approx 23.9788 - 280.9484i, \qquad q\approx -79435.9450 + 3360.6067i\\ 
r &\approx 887.1924 - 1622.2486i, \quad s\approx -10877.3102 + 5356.5441i
\end{align}

The correct roots $(p,q,r,s)$ can be ascertained by the two relationships above. Note the sextics in $(q,r)$ are **palindromic**. (*Now why is that?*) Method 2 then yields,

$$x_k = \frac{1}{7}\left(\frac{1}{\beta^{-1}}-\frac{1}{\beta^0}+\frac{43}{\beta^1}+\frac{43\color{red}p}{\beta^2}+\frac{43^2r}{\beta^3}+\frac{43^2s}{\beta^4}+\frac{43^3\color{red}q}{\beta^5} \right)$$

where $\color{blue}{\beta^7-y_1=0}.$ Again, only one $7$th root extraction is needed.

---

**IV. Questions**

1. Why can we factor the resolvent equation of degree $n$ into two equations with *same* degree $n$ and *smaller* coefficients? (Almost akin to how we factor composite integers into smaller integers.) Is it implicit in Galois theory that the resolvent is a "composite" algebraic number, or must certain conditions be satisfied?
2. And why does one factor have palindromic coefficients? (For $p=11$, then $b/11^2$ is also a root of a palindrome.)